# Appending JS to the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to append my variables 'showName' and 'showDescription' to the 'results' div object. I have tried to add them in using 'innerHTML' but I just get the description shown. I have tried making additional divs to put INSIDE the 'results' div but that didn't work either.

I want the 'showName' to appear above the 'showDescription in the div.

I am challenging myself to not use JQuery so that is not a viable option.

code:

```
document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener('keypress', function(e){//On button click of enter, get the value of the search bar and concatanate it to the end of the url
  if(e.key==='Enter'){
    var query = document.getElementById('main').value;
    var url = fetch("http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q="+query) //use fetch to get the data from the url, THEN convert it to json THEN console.log the data.
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)

      var domObject = document.createElement('div')
      domObject.id="myDiv";
      domObject.style.width="800px";
      domObject.style.height="5000px";
      domObject.style.display="flex";
      domObject.style.flexDirection="column";
      domObject.style.margin="auto";
      domObject.style.borderRadius="30px";
      domObject.style.background="";
      document.body.appendChild(domObject);

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //for all the items returned, loop through each one and show the name of the show and the dsescription of the show.
        var showName = data[i].show.name;
        //console.log(showName);
        var showDescription = data[i].show.summary
//console.log(showDescription);
        var results = document.createElement('div')
        results.id="myResults";
        results.style.width="600px"
        results.style.height="400px";
        results.style.background="white";
        results.style.margin="auto";
        results.style.borderRadius="30px";
        results.style.fontFamily="Poppins"
        results.style.display="flex";
        results.style.flexDirection="column";
        results.innerHTML=showName;
        results.innerHTML=showDescription;
        document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(results);
      }
    })
  }
});
document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener('keydown', function(o){
  if(o.key==='Backspace'){
    location.reload();
  }
});
```

result of searching in 'car'

[image]

Comment: In your loop, you set the newly created div's `innerHtml` once then overwrite it: `results.innerHTML = showName;` then on the next line you overwrite the `showName` data -> `results.innerHTML = showDescription;`, try changing to `results.innerHTML += showDescription;`

Comment: The second `innerHTML` will override the first one, so use this: `results.innerHTML = showName + showDescription`

Comment: I am new to the DOM, can u only use innerHTML once?

Comment: @Marvin You can use it as much as you want. It's a property. The problem is that you assign it's value twice. You need to append rather than assign when adding the description. See my previous comment. Give this a read - (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 1):

```
results.innerHTML = showName;
results.innerHTML = showDescription;
```

With this you are overwriting `showName` with `showDescription`.
What you need to do is concatenate with `+=`.

Also, it will be much easier to replace this:

```
domObject.style.width = "800px";
domObject.style.height = "5000px";
domObject.style.display = "flex";
domObject.style.flexDirection = "column";
domObject.style.margin = "auto";
domObject.style.borderRadius = "30px";
domObject.style.background = "";
```

with `domObject.classList.add('some-class');`

and CSS will be:

```
.some-class {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't realise I can edit the css in the css file not on the JS

Answer (score 1):

Moved your code to a working example.

Note: because of authors styles, it is only possible to run snippet in fullscreen. =)

```js
const dosearch = () => {
  var query = document.getElementById('main').value;
  var url = fetch("https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=" + query)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
      myDiv.innerHTML = ''; // <---- this is for testing
      
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var showName = data[i].show.name;
        var showDescription = data[i].show.summary

        var results = document.createElement('div');
        results.className = 'myResults';

        var header = document.createElement('h2');
        header.innerHTML = showName;
        results.appendChild(header);

        var desc = document.createElement('div');
        desc.innerHTML = showDescription;
        results.appendChild(desc);

        myDiv.appendChild(results);
      }
    });
}

document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    dosearch();
  }
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 800px;
  height: 5000px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: black;
}

.myResults {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: Poppins;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.myResults p, .myResults h2 {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="main" class="search" style="margin-bottom: 4px" value="Car" /><button onclick="dosearch()">Go</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh you have literally refactored my code and finished my entire project!!! Comparing both I can see how much better your version is. I will refactor my code in this style, just looking through it I can see so many better practises to use. I will take this as a learning curve and try a new project using these techniques. Thank you for your help!